# Use of randomAccessFileOrArray()

Tags: java, pdf, itext

can anyone explain me what is the use of randomAccessFileOrArray() function in iText and how it is diferent from using Files.readAllBytes().

I am using following line of code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Files.readAllBytes((new File(filenameSource)).toPath()));
```

But at runtime, I met with java heap space error, so I found out the following option:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filenameSource),null);
```

But I am not quite sure what difference does this create. Can anyone help me out here please?

Answer (score 2):

As you use both the [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) and the [itext7](/questions/tagged/itext7) tag, it is unclear which iText version you use. Considering the code you quote, though, it cannot be iText version 7 as there a `PdfReader` does not accept a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` as constructor argument.

**In iText 5**, no matter which `PdfReader` constructor you use, eventually internally a `RandomAccessSource` implementation is used to access the pdf. This interface *Represents an abstract source that bytes can be read from*. The main data retrieval method in that interface is

```
public int get(long position, byte bytes[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

making this essentially a generalized `InputStream`, adding the `position` parameter for random access.

`RandomAccessFileOrArray` actually merely wraps a `RandomAccessSource` and provides a number of methods for retrieving data in specific formats (`readChar`, `readFloat`, `readLine`, ...). When used in a `PdfReader` constructor, only that underlying `RandomAccessSource` is used.

If constructed for a file name, it generates a `RAFRandomAccessSource` based on a `RandomAccessFile` for the named file, just like

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filenameSource);
```

would do.

An important difference, though: When using the `RandomAccessFileOrArray` based `PdfReader` constructor the `PdfReader` handles the PDF in ***partial*** mode, i.e. it only reads the parts it needs for the desired operations on the PDF and forgets them as soon as they are not needed anymore. Otherwise, the PDF is parsed completely and kept in memory the whole time.

A `byte[]` in a `PdfReader` constructor will be wrapped in an `ArrayRandomAccessSource` and loaded completely, not in partial mode.

The differences between the approaches are, therefore, which exact implementation of that interface is used to read the pdf bytes and whether or not partial mode is used (with an impact on memory use):

- In case of

  ```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Files.readAllBytes((new File(filenameSource)).toPath()));
  ```

  the pdf is first loaded into a `byte[]` in memory, an array that is as big as the original pdf, which then in turn is used by `PdfReader` to parse the whole PDF from.

  Memory requirements: The size of the original PDF plus the size of the complete parsed PDF.
- In case of

  ```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filenameSource);
  ```

  `PdfReader` (via the `RAFRandomAccessSource` instance) immediately reads from the file on disk without a `byte[]` in-between and parses the whole PDF.

  Memory requirements: The size of the complete parsed PDF.
- In case of

  ```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filenameSource),null);
  ```

  `PdfReader` (via the `RAFRandomAccessSource` instance) immediately reads from the file on disk without a `byte[]` in-between and parses only the parts of the PDF used in your processing.

  Memory requirements: The size of the partially parsed PDF.

Thus, in case of large PDFs there is a substantial difference between the resource hunger of these three approaches.

Performance differences depend on your use case; if you manipulate large parts of your PDF, partial reading will be slower. If you only manipulate some details, partial reading will be faster. Furthermore, if you need to delete the file you read from quickly (while still processing it), a `byte[]` based solution is the approach of choice.

Thus, it makes sense to know all approaches and use them depending on the use case at hand.

Comment: So, there is no memory mapping concept involved in latter (RandomAccessFileOrArray)?

Comment: No, no memory mapping is involved (except if used in a `RandomAccessFile` implementation in the Java library version you use). While checking that, though, I realized that you actually use iText 5.x (or ealier), not iText 7, while my original answer assumed something like iText 7 because of the [tag:itext7] tag you used. I adapted the answer to iText 5 details. Here another factor, the partial PDF parsing mode, has to be considered, too.